# Converting date to time and checking if it between two dates

Tags: php, time

I got two dates ($date_from and $date_to).

I want to check if those dates are between date a and b. If not, check if those dates are between date x and y.

However I want to do that by converting them to their timestamp, but because this should work for every year I am automatically defining the current year.

```
    $date_from = strtotime($date_from);
    $date_to = strtotime($date_to);

    $year = date("Y");
    $msg = $year;
    $x1 = '25/3/'.$year;

    $contractDateBegin = strtotime($x1);
    $contractDateEnd = strtotime('30/6/'.$year);

    $contractDateBegin2 = strtotime('17/8/'.$year);
    $contractDateEnd2 = strtotime('16/10/'.$year);

    if ($date_from >= $contractDateBegin && $date_to <= $contractDateEnd)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ($date_from >= $contractDateBegin2 && $date_to <= $contractDateEnd2)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Here, `$x` outputs 25/3/2016, but `$contractDateBegin` outputs nothing. Why?

Comment: Dates with a `/` separator are treated as `mm/dd/yyyy`; and there is no 3rd day of the 25th month of a year, so it's an invalid date.... if you want to use UK/European `dd-mm-yyyy` format, then use a `-` or `.` separator... [PHP Docs](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: the date format yyyy-mm-dd ('Y-m-d') lends itself much better to sorting/comparing.   As a naming convention, it's best to prefix any "timestamp" variables with "ts".   ie `$tsDateFrom`, `$tsContractDateBegin`, etc   so you know at a glance it's an int, rather than a string

Comment: When using `.` instead of `-` it works like a charm. Thank you guys.